# issue in java runtime

Tags: java

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits on lenovo z5070 laptop.

I've installed java on my laptop but I think that It doesn't work correctly. Because It usually warn me about a problem and make a log file.
I've been attached the log file [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11468086/)

would you please help me?

thanks

mansoor